# C# WPF Update Label before and after processing - immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have already tried several online examples (Thread, Dispatcher, await/async) but none is working for me in my C#/WPF project.

I have the following button click method:

```
private void BtnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        this.lblResponse.Content = "";

        executeInstall(); //do some work

        this.lblResponse.Content = "DONE";
    }
```

The label gets updated afterwards to DONE, but when I click again on the button the label isnt getting emptied before the processing of executeInstall.
As I mentioned I already tried several different examples from other questions (Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, Thread, Task, await/async) but none of them has worked - the label change before is never done before the processing of executeInstall.

I am working in .NET framework 4.7.2.

Is there maybe a setting that debug mode only executes the program with one thread and thats maybe why none of the solutions works for me?

Comment: async await is your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for that.

```
private async void BtnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.lblResponse.Content = "";

    await Task.Run(()=> executeInstall());

    this.lblResponse.Content = "DONE";
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you need to access the UI inside your `executeIntall` method you will need to invoke the [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.8). In this case you would need to delay the [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) to give the label time to update before the install starts. Note that this will cause the UI to freeze during the entire install.

```
private async void BtnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lblResponse.Content = "starting...";

    await Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(_=>
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            executeInstall();
            lblResponse.Content = "DONE";
        });
    });
}
```

A better approach would be to only call the dispatcher when it's actually needed. This would keep the UI responsive during the entire process.

```
private async void BtnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lblResponse.Content = "starting...";
    await Task.Run(()=> executeInstall());
    lblResponse.Content = "DONE";
}

private void executeInstall()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //do time consuming operation
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblResponse.Content = "Downloading Files...");
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //do time consuming operation
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblResponse.Content = "Unzipping Files...");
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //do time consuming operation
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblResponse.Content = "Updating Files...");
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //do time consuming operation
}
```